# Method Swizzling in Android using java

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to do method swizzling in android using java? i would like to intercept a system method and log its parameters then process it normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that technique could not be used using Java in any environment.

Maybe you could achieve a similar result using AOP.

But what you can do with that looks limited on Android. See [Aspect-oriented programming in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3759232/127035). In fact, since you won't be compiling the target code (system method), compile-time weaving (which appears to be all you could use on Android) will be useless for this case. As is this answer I suppose.

One other thought... I guess you want to do this logging consistently. But if you needed this to debug a problem, you could do it using a [conditional breakpoint in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-manage_conditional_breakpoint.htm).

> A conditional expression can contain arbitrary Java code and may
>   contain more than one statement, allowing breakpoint conditions to
>   implement features like tracing. For example, a condition can execute
>   a print statement and then return a hard coded value to never suspend
>   ("System.out.println(...); return false;").

I don't know specifically whether this works with methods in the Android SDK. But it does work with methods in the Java SDK. For example, here is simple code:

```
    System.err.println("foo");
```

I made a conditional breakpoint in PrintStream.print, like this:

```
System.err.println("hello: " + arg0);
return false;
```

And the console output when debugging in the program is this:

```
hello: foo
foo
```

Note that since the JDK is not compiled with debug symbols, I can't refer to method parameters by name, but using the `arg0..argn`.

Comment: does this also apply of api methods from the android sdk ?